# wordpress php loop - archive is looping the same number of times as results

Tags: php, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Not sure that's the best way to to describe it, but here's what's happening (and I'm sure this has to be a reasonably easy thing, just not sure where to look):

Client has 10 offices so I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin with a custom post type to specify a location for job postings. My code seems to be working (i.e. it's pulling the appropriate jobs by location) but it's looping the     **article** tag the same number of times as results. I have 3 jobs in there, so it loops the whole set of results 3 times. If I delete one and drop down to 2, it loops twice, etc. I used the following example from the advanced custom fields website:

```
<?php 
// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'jobs',
    'meta_key'      => 'location',
    'meta_value'    => 'akron' 
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <h3>Akron Office</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

I guess I'm not sure where to look (I realize this might be a plugin question rather than a php question) and would appreciate any direction you guys can provide.

You can see the offending page here: http://www.knrlegal.com/jobs/

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the post data, not the query, as stated here:
[Class Reference/WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), in the "Multiple Loops" section.

```
        <?php 
    // args
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'jobs',
        'meta_key'      => 'location',
        'meta_value'    => 'akron' 
    );

    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <h3>Akron Office</h3>
        <ul>
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php 
     /* Restore original Post Data 
     * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
     * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset with 
     * wp_reset_query(). We just need to set the post data back up with
     * wp_reset_postdata().
     */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>    
    <?php endif; ?>
```